# PHP Session not working on some(times) mobile users?

Tags: php, session

I'm creating session for user orderid (siparisno), some users get error

> "u have no orderid".

working with php7

```
//function1
//creating orderid(siparisno)
$rand1=rand(10,99);
$rand2=rand(10,99);
$rand3=rand(10,99);
$siparisno_manuel=date("dmy").strtotime("now").$rand1.$rand2.$rand3;
$siparisno=$siparisno_manuel;
$_SESSION["siparisno"]=$siparisno;

//function2
//getting orderid
@ob_start();
include __DIR__ . '/../view/success.php';
$buffer=@ob_get_clean();
$siparisno=$_SESSION["siparisno"];//GETTING HERE SESSION
if ($siparisno==null){
    $string="<h3>Your order number could not be created. Please repeat your order.(error_code: $siparisno)</h3>";
    $buffer=str_replace("{string}",$string,$buffer);
    echo $buffer;
}else{
    //create order with orderid
}
```

Some android users getting

> "Your order number could not be created. Please repeat your order (error_code:)"

User:"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A520F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.111 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Comment: So where is the `session_start()`

Comment: Can you show your actual code and its separation from each other (you mention function, where are the function definitions, how and when is each called?)

Comment: _Small Point_ `$siparisno=$siparisno_manuel;
$_SESSION["siparisno"]=$siparisno;` why the intermediary variable, it serves no purpose

Comment: Don't silence the errors. They are useful.

Comment: _Medium Sized Point_ Nowhere in the code you show us is there anything that will produce a message to the user like `"u have no orderid"`

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and **most importantly** how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Kodun tumu bumudur yardimci olacagim ama tam ne yapmak istedigini anlamadim 

Answer (score 0):

Missing session_start() top of page ,
if you are use for restapi can't data store to session because sessions is stateless ...

```
seesion_start();
```

Ingilizcem bu kadar

Comment: Öncelikle cevabın için teşekkür ederim. session_start(); var hatta tekrar eklemeye çalıştığım için header uyarısı verdi. Ama malesef bazı kullanıcılarda session oluşmuyor. Yani şöyle bahsedeyim üyenin kart bilgilerini post ediyorum bir sayfaya orda session oluşturuyorum siparisno diye  sonra üye 3d secure sayfasına yönlendiriliyor. Sms'ine gelen şifreyi girdikten sonra bizim sayfamıza tekrar yönleniyor ama yönlendikten sonra session (siparisno) oluşmadığı için adamın siparişini oluşturamıyorum. Müşterilerin %98' inde sorun yokken bazılarında bu problem oluyor genellikle android kullanıcıları.

Comment: Session nasil olusur stateless nedir statesfull kavramlari be header ile aciklarsak daha konu tam oturur stateless her request bilgi gonderilir mesela rest apilerde session tutamazsin php Ile istesende tutamaz peki nasil olursa php her seferinde sessionu tutar headerden gelen data ile php onu okur boylece sessionu user bilgilerini tutar artik her seferinde kullanici bilgisini gondermeye gerek yok session kullanici bilgilerini tutar bunada statesfulll denir bu asamada Boyle hatta almis olabilirsin ...kullanici cok ise sessionlari redise yazdirmayi dene